# Did David sacrifice every six steps in 2 Samuel 6:13?

Tags: david, symbolism, 2-samuel, sacrifice

2 Samuel 6:13 NIV

> 13 When those who were carrying the ark of the Lord had taken six steps, he sacrificed a bull and a fattened calf.

In the above text David is said to have offered a sacrifice after six steps but its not clear whether he did this for every six steps or just once.

How should we understand the above text?

Answer (score 1):

Various commentaries allow room for either scenario (once at six paces or every six paces). Below offers a bit of rationale:

**Historical Linguistics and Biblical Hebrew: Steps Toward an Integrated** ...

By Robert Rezetko, Ian Young

[GoogleBooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=rwS5BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA486&lpg=PA486&dq=2Sam.%206:13,%20six%20paces%20or%20steps&source=bl&ots=CFzLSJz1lW&sig=ACfU3U3u43L1CCD9TMkfJ-3Ry8SPmzxKZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjio6fXwrjoAhVYl3IEHV0xCnA4ChDoATAHegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=2Sam.%206%3A13%2C%20six%20paces%20or%20steps&f=false)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a parallel account recorded in

> 1 Chronicles 15:25 So David and the elders of Israel and the commanders of units of a thousand went to bring up the ark of the covenant of the Lord from the house of Obed-Edom, with rejoicing. 26 Because God had helped the Levites who were carrying the ark of the covenant of the Lord, **seven bulls and seven rams were sacrificed**.

That seem to be the summary of sacrifices.

More sacrifices were performed at the destination, in

> 1 Chronicles 16:1
> They brought the ark of God and set it inside the tent that David had pitched for it, and they presented **burnt offerings and fellowship offerings** before God.

Sacrificing after six every steps all the way to Zion practically is not likely.